# Deleting multiple lines in csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a large log of csv files that I want to delete until the nearer to current date depend upon my provided input.
Objectives:
 
* Minimizing the content of my csv log file.
* If the chosen date are not found, retain whole log by writing again the file(because as far as I know we read it again and again if we are doing something).
Form:
 I had a form contain browse button and one textbox named: "txtfilename" (display the directory here). Datagridview in viewing my csv file. Datetimepicker were I can choose the date. One button to delete multiple lines until the choosen date.
Code task:
  Reading the whole lines using streamreader. "If" condition to evaluate if the chosen date has been found and break the line. Streamwriter to write the rest of the lines. Note! upon reading it include the header to delete, So I used writer again with a tempfile that hold the rest of the lines and insert a header at the beginning of the line. 

Code bugs:
* If I choose again the filtered file. error says: process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Lacking Codes:
* How to close streamreader.
* How to write again the whole lines if the reader cannot encounter the date given by datetimepicker.
Sample csv file:
"EmployeeCode","Date","Time","Type"
"3434","01/22/2013","07:54","0"
"3023","01/23/2013","07:54","0"
......  .....   ....  .....
......  .....   ....  .....
......  .....   ....  .....
"4863","01/26/2017","07:55","0"
"2513","01/28/2017","07:55","0"
"2582","01/29/2017","07:55","0"

```
  private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    String line = null;

    String tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();          

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(txtFileName.Text))
    {
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
      {
       while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
         if (line.Contains(dateTimePicker1.Text)) //reading if the line contains the date by datetimepicker.
         { 
           writer.WriteLine("\"EmployeeCode\",\"Date\",\"Time\",\"Type\"");

           writer.WriteLine(line); 

           break; // stop reading the line if it encounter the given date.
         }                       
       }   
    //writing the lines after the break                 
       while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
         writer.WriteLine(line);
       }                  
      }            
    }
      if (File.Exists(tempFile))
       {
         File.Delete(txtFileName.Text);  
         File.Move(tempFile, txtFileName.Text);
       }
        string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempfile))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(txtFileName.Text))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("\"EmployeeCode\",\"Date\",\"Time\",\"Type\"");
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
        File.Copy(tempfile, txtFileName.Text, true);     
        //reload the datagridview   
        Import();

        Application.DoEvents();
  }
```

Code above is running but need to improve base of my statements above.

## Note! One filename processing - used TempFile.

Comment: You don't need to close `StreamReader` since `using` is calling `Dispose()` which closes the `StreamReader`.

Comment: I was just typing what @JanesAbouChleih said but for the rest you need to provide more details. I'm not sure what the first question is about. Or what the exact problem is.

Comment: //write some comments in code to explain

Comment: If the line are contain the datetimepicker value using the code: if (line.Contains(dateTimePicker1.Text)) it will break the line. Then if the line does not contain the datetimepicker value therefore I need to write the whole line again. That is my first problem.

Comment: As I understand it if the datetime given doesn't exist then you want to just write the original file contents out? If so why don't you just do nothing? There is no point creating a temp file identical to the original and then replacing the original with it. If this isn't what you want then you need to be clearer about your requirements.

Comment: Side note: `Application.DoEvents();` oh, no! Put the routine into `Task` and await it

Comment: Hope that everyone may understand the beginner in programming. Don't easily vote down. Advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: @LovExpert: The downvoting is not going to be because you are a beginner in programming but because it isn't clear what this question is asking. For example you write "This is to delete a large file log." but then you don't actually delete the log file but instead do some modifications to it. Did you mean that we are removing old data from the log file? This looks like what it is trying to do but I shouldn't be needing to understand your intent from reading the code - your question should explain things in detail with the code then being your attempt at doing what you described.

Comment: Also as coding advice to a beginner - you have two variables, one called `tempFile` and one `tempfile` - don't do this. It only makes it harder to understand your code since at a glance they both look the same but will likely hold different values - using the wrong one accidentally will cause major problems.

Comment: Okay, I will make it clear. I'm not really good but I'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest getting rid of `Readers`, `Writers`, `Streams`, but using `File` class; something like that:

```
   private static void ProcessLog(string sourceFileName, 
                                  string targetFileName, 
                                  string textToFind) {   
     // Do nothing if "file contains the date given by DateTimePicker"
     if (File
          .ReadLines(fileName)
          .Any(line => line.Contains(textToFind))) 
       return;

     // "Write again the whole file" ( == copy it ?)
     File.Copy(sourceFileName, targetFileName, true);
   }

   private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     ProcessLog(txtFileName.Text, Path.GetTempFileName(), dateTimePicker1.Text);

     ...
   }
```

**Edit:** In case I've misunderstood you and you actually want to *skip* all lines before the 1st DateTimePicker's date occurrence and then write the rest lines down (see Chris's comment):

```
   private static void ProcessLog(string sourceFileName, 
                                  string targetFileName, 
                                  string textToFind) {   
     File
       .WriteAllLines(targetFileName, File
         .ReadLines(sourceFileName)
         .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(textToFind)));
   }
```

Comment: "// Do nothing if "file contains the date given by DateTimePicker"" - this is not what the original does. The original doesn't write any lines from the original until it finds the datetime and then writes all lines after that. ie it removes the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Chris: I see, thank you! I've edited the answer (skipping top file's lines until DateTimePicker's date is found)

Comment: I think its a combination of both (the perils of trying to keep comments short mean I don't think I explained my interpretation of the OP) but at this point I think we need clarification from the OP on exact requirements. So while I'm not sure your answer is a full answer, it should give the OP the pieces needed to sort themselves out.

Comment: @Chris: I'm totally agree with you that the question should have been explained in a better way (when given log file what is the desired outcome). However, I think that using `File` class and *Linq* can simplify the routine (whatever outcome is actually required) dramatically and that is the reason I've put it as an answer

Comment: Yup. Agreed. My point was just that your code might not be copy and pastable as a solution but it has all the right ideas so if the OP understands what you are doing they should be able to modify it for their own requirements. Its why you got my +1. :)